# Attach custom metric to HitBuilders.TransactionBuilder in Android Analytics v4

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

How can I attach a custom metric value to `HitBuilders.TransactionBuilder` in the following fashion? I want to associate a transaction with a value.

`tracker.send(new HitBuilders.TransactionBuilder()
.setOtherAttributes(...)
.setCustomMetric(1, 10)
.build());`

The rest of the data are successfully sent, but the custom metric is always 0.

Comment: Can you please enable verbose logging and copy/paste GAv4 logcat output? Is the custom metric not sent or you just don't see it in your report?

Comment: I have `analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);`, but it's not displaying logs on logcat. It does not appear on the report and I haven't been able to verify whether it does send the custom metric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with that the scope of the custom metric was not Hit and that I was looking at a custom report widget matched by Product. The value appeared when I changed the column.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is correct. You can try to setCustomDimension instead of setCustomMetric, you only have to transform float to string.

Comment: I've also verified that the custom metric is set up on the analytics account. I just can't find a reason why it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. What you need to check is the server side reports you build.

Make sure you created a Custom metric in Admin - Custom Definitions - Custom metrics. Once created, custom metrics will initially appear with a 3 to 4 hours delay on the server. Give them some time to appear there. Finally, you need to create a report to see the result. Make sure you choose the right time intervals and don't add too many metric and filters, otherwise you won't see data. Make first reposts as simple as possible. I hope this helps.